# how to add new rows into a datatable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a form with a textbox and a "add" button.

1. The user can write a name down on the textbox and click the "add" button. It will save in a datatable with auto ID.
2. After that, the textbox is cleared and the user can write another name in the text box and click the button.
3. This should add to the existing datatable in memory with existing ID + 1.
4. Then show in the gridview. (this is just for display purpose to confirm it works)

I have a datatable like this.

```
    Button1.click() event

    Dim name = txtname.Text
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    Dim N As Integer = dt.Columns("ID").AutoIncrement
    dt.Rows.Add(N, name)
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    txtname.Text = ""
```

At the moment I have sometime like the code above. in the real program, it is not just name and it is not just one datatable so i just mock up some code.

and this code for aspx.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

can anyone advice me how to do it ? i understand my code is crapped and not correct but i just have to put some code so that you guys not need to work from scratch for me.

Thanks so much.

Comment: i can't believe i asked this question :(

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is an example of adding a new row to a datatable that uses AutoIncrement on the first column:

Define the table structure:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns(0).AutoIncrement = True
```

Add a New row:

```
    Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    R("Name") = txtName.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(R)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: it adds the name but it replaces the previous name at row (0)

Comment: Don't define your datatable in the button click event if it has prior data you need to retain it at a wider scope.  That way you can add to it, without ever calling New and removing all prior data.  If you go with Private dt as datatable at the class level, define the structure somewhere like on load (but not on post back) when you add a row in the button click to dt it won't clear all the existing information first.

Comment: Thanks Dear D ... it works now .. ya, the problem was that i put in on button click event of course, it wipe out and create new dt everytime how stupid i was :D ... thanks for your answer, this will give me a very good start for my real program to develop .. good day !

Comment: OMG .. I did actually ask this question .. it looks so silly now.

Answer (score 8):

First You need to define the data table structure as like the following:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("Name",Type.GetType("System.String"))
```

And Then add row like:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr("ID") = System.GUID.NewGUID()
dr("Name") = txtName.Text
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataBind()
```