# I encounter this NoNullAllowedException when I try to add a new row to my data table in Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me with this

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.NoNullAllowedException' occurred in System.Data.dll  Additional information: Column 'TrainingSessionIndex' does not allow nulls.

I get this at   'Add a new row to the Operator table.
                `rw = TestdbDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Add()`

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As TestdbDataSet
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Fill retrieves rows from the data source by using the SELECT statement
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Infane\Documents\Testdb.accdb")
            Using da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OperatorDb", con)
                da.Fill(ds)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Infane\Documents\Testdb.accdb")
            Using da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OperatorDb", con)

                Dim i, OperatorIndex As Integer
                Dim Department As String
                Dim FirstName As String
                Dim LastName As String
                Dim Password As String
                Dim EmailAddress As String
                Dim rw As TestdbDataSet.OperatorDbRow
                Dim myBuilder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)


                'Add a new row to the Operator table.
                rw = TestdbDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Add()

                OperatorIndex = InputBox("Enter your OperatorIndex")
                Department = InputBox("Enter your Department")
                FirstName = InputBox("Enter your FirstName")
                LastName = InputBox("Enter your LastName")
                Password = InputBox("Enter your Password")
                EmailAddress = InputBox("Enter your email address")

                rw.Item("OperatorIndex") = OperatorIndex
                rw.Item("Department") = Department
                rw.Item("FirstName") = FirstName
                rw.Item("LastName") = LastName
                rw.Item("Enter your password") = Password
                rw.Item("Enter your EmailAddress") = EmailAddress

                Try
                    'Update the Student table in the testdb database.
                    myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
                    da.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
                    i = da.Update(TestdbDataSet1, "OperatorDb")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
                'Displays number of rows updated. 
                MessageBox.Show("no of rows updated=" & i)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of [how to add new rows into a datatable vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297506/how-to-add-new-rows-into-a-datatable-vb-net).

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that one of the columns is constrained to disallow null values.  In this case you are calling `Add` with no arguments and hence null will be the default.  You need to provide valid parameters to the `Add` method in order for this to work