# Filling up a datagridview row with variables set for each cell

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, datagridview

Currently I am able to import my excel sheet into DataGridView.
However when I try to add a whole new row based on different variables for each column of that row it doesn't like it.

I was hoping to use

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {txt_id.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_modelnumber})
```

However I'm getting a error saying
"Additional information: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

How do I make it not databound? Or is there another way to populate the cells?

My import code :

```
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\Test\exported.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Products$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: You need to add the rows to the object you specified is the datasource of the datagridview not the datagridview itself

Comment: I'll see if I can read up on datasourcesand adding rows however I'm quite confused at the minute.
My datasource is just imported from a xlsx file.
Is it possible to do the "DataGridView1.Rows.Add" way or do I have to do is explicitly the other way?
Also in what case would "DataGridView1.Rows.Add" be used if not this?

Comment: You must be assigning the `datagridview1.datasource = ?????` somewhere. What are you assiging it to? Show the code you are using to import the excel sheet into the grid. `DataGridView1.Rows.Add` is used when your grid is Not bound to a datasource as the error states

Comment: So you need to add rows to the DataTable `DtSet.Tables(0)` instead of the grid. The new rows will show automatically in the grid.

Comment: I've added my import code into the main question. It seems that my datasource is the dataset that is being filled with the information from the excel sheet. Is it possible to make it not bound to a data source so I just import my data and then from there it's no longer linked. Or something similar to that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other method that Matt Wilko posted however I wasn't able to grasp how I could use that. So I looked it up on the microsoft library and found something that worked perfectly.

```
    Dim table As DataTable = DtSet.Tables(0)
    Dim newRow As DataRow = table.NewRow()
    newRow("Product ID") = lastproductid + 1
    newRow("Name") = txt_name.Text
    table.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: This uses the method that I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you assign a DataSource to a DataGridView, you cannot add rows to the DataGridView directly, you must add them to the DataSource.

In your case you need to add rows to the DataTable `dtSet.Tables(0)`

See: [how to add new rows into a datatable vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297506/how-to-add-new-rows-into-a-datatable-vb-net)

Your only other option is to add all the rows in the DataTable to the Grid manually like this:

```
For each dr As DataRow In dtSet.Tables(0).Rows
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {dr.Item(0).ToString, etc})
Loop
```

Comment: I tried the first option however the only result I've gotten from that is it completely emptying the imported datagridview and replacing with a row I set it. I'll try the second method now though.